# What's the meaning of core number in ThreadScope?

Tags: haskell

I'm confused with the ThreadScope usage, when I want to profile my haskell program, and follow the steps:

```sh
> ghc -threaded -eventlog -rtsopts --make test.hs
> test.exe +RTS -ls -N2
> threadscope test.exe.eventlog
```

and I find two cores in threadscope , but when I modify step two like:

```
> test.exe +RTS -ls -N6
```

(I actually have four cores in my computer), threadscope show 6 cores in its user interface, what's that meaning?

Comment: What happens if you just do `test.exe +RTS -ls -N`?  By not specifying a number after the `-N`, it will use all available cores on your computer.  It could be that you have a quad-core processor, but thanks to features like hyperthreading it appears to your OS that you have 8 cores (this is the case for my computer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That aren't cores, but [HECs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ThreadScope):

> The program displays the activity on each Haskell Execution Context (HEC) which roughly corresponds to an operating system thread.

And [`-N[x]`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/using-smp.html#parallel-options) will set the number of threads to `x`:

> `-N[x]`
>
> > Use *`x`* simultaneous threads when
> >                   running the program.  Normally *`x`*
> >                   should be chosen to match the number of CPU cores on the
> >                   machine. For example,
> >                   on a dual-core machine we would probably use
> >                   `+RTS -N2 -RTS`.
> >
> > Omitting *`x`*,
> >                   i.e. `+RTS -N -RTS`, lets the runtime
> >                   choose the value of *`x`* itself
> >                   based on how many processors are in your machine.

And since you used `-N6`, you observe 6 HECs.